# I'm trying to group by 2 different elements in XSLT. First by HOSTLOCID, then by HOSTVENDORLOCID

Tags: xslt, soa

Below is the XSLT that i 've created based on the previous inputs to some one elses question in this group

```
 <xsl:for-each-group select="/ns0:PurchaseOrders/ns0:PO" group-by="ns0:HOSTLOCID">
        <tns:E1PORDCR1>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()" group-by="ns0:HOSTVENDORLOCID">
       
        <tns:E1BPMEPOHEADER>
        
          <tns:COMP_CODE>
            <xsl:value-of select="ns0:HOSTLOCID"/>
          </tns:COMP_CODE>
            <xsl:choose>
              <xsl:when test="ns0:ORDERTYPEID = 1">
                <tns:DOC_TYPE>NB</tns:DOC_TYPE>
              </xsl:when>
              <xsl:when test="ns0:ORDERTYPEID = 5">
                <tns:DOC_TYPE>ZNB</tns:DOC_TYPE>
              </xsl:when>
            </xsl:choose>
            
            <xsl:choose>
              <xsl:when test="ns0:ORDERTYPEID = 1">
                <tns:VENDOR>
                  <xsl:value-of select="ns0:HOSTVENDORLOCID"/>
                </tns:VENDOR>
              </xsl:when>


              <xsl:when test="ns0:ORDERTYPEID = 5">
                <tns:VENDOR>
                  <xsl:value-of select="ns0:HOSTREPLSOURCELOCID"/>
                </tns:VENDOR>
              </xsl:when>
            </xsl:choose>
          </tns:E1BPMEPOHEADER>
         
        </xsl:for-each-group>
         </tns:E1PORDCR1>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
```

Below is the input i am sending

```
<PurchaseOrders>
    
    <PO>
        <HOSTLOCID>100-0001</HOSTLOCID>
        <HOSTPARTID>100</HOSTPARTID>
        <HOSTVENDORLOCID>IC100</HOSTVENDORLOCID>
    </PO>
    <PO>
        <HOSTLOCID>100-0001</HOSTLOCID>
        <HOSTPARTID>200</HOSTPARTID>
        <HOSTVENDORLOCID>IC200</HOSTVENDORLOCID>
    </PO>
    <PO>
        <HOSTLOCID>100-0001</HOSTLOCID>
        <HOSTPARTID>300</HOSTPARTID>
        <HOSTVENDORLOCID>IC100</HOSTVENDORLOCID>
    </PO>
    <PO>
        <HOSTLOCID>100-0002</HOSTLOCID>
        <HOSTPARTID>400</HOSTPARTID>
        <HOSTVENDORLOCID>IC100</HOSTVENDORLOCID>
    </PO>    <PO>
        <HOSTLOCID>100-0003</HOSTLOCID>
        <HOSTPARTID>500</HOSTPARTID>
        <HOSTVENDORLOCID>IC300</HOSTVENDORLOCID>
    </PO>
    <PO>
        <HOSTLOCID>100-0002</HOSTLOCID>
        <HOSTPARTID>600</HOSTPARTID>
        <HOSTVENDORLOCID>IC100</HOSTVENDORLOCID>
    </PO>    <PO>
        <HOSTLOCID>100-0001</HOSTLOCID>
        <HOSTPARTID>700</HOSTPARTID>
        <HOSTVENDORLOCID>IC100</HOSTVENDORLOCID>
    </PO>
    <PO>
        <HOSTLOCID>100-0003</HOSTLOCID>
        <HOSTPARTID>800</HOSTPARTID>
        <HOSTVENDORLOCID>IC300</HOSTVENDORLOCID>
    </PO>   
</PurchaseOrders>
```

What I would like as output

```
<PO_Group>
<PurchaseOrders>
    <!-- Group by Plant-Loc/Supplier -->
    <PO>
        <HOSTLOCID>100-0001</HOSTLOCID>
        <HOSTPARTID>100</HOSTPARTID>
        <HOSTVENDORLOCID>IC100</HOSTVENDORLOCID>
    </PO>
    <PO>
        <HOSTLOCID>100-0001</HOSTLOCID>
        <HOSTPARTID>300</HOSTPARTID>
        <HOSTVENDORLOCID>IC100</HOSTVENDORLOCID>
    </PO>
    <PO>
        <HOSTLOCID>100-0001</HOSTLOCID>
        <HOSTPARTID>700</HOSTPARTID>
        <HOSTVENDORLOCID>IC100</HOSTVENDORLOCID>
    </PO>
</PurchaseOrders>
<PurchaseOrders>
    <!-- Group by Plant-Loc/Supplier -->
    <PO>
        <HOSTLOCID>100-0002</HOSTLOCID>
        <HOSTPARTID>400</HOSTPARTID>
        <HOSTVENDORLOCID>IC100</HOSTVENDORLOCID>
    </PO>   
    <PO>
        <HOSTLOCID>100-0002</HOSTLOCID>
        <HOSTPARTID>600</HOSTPARTID>
        <HOSTVENDORLOCID>IC100</HOSTVENDORLOCID>
    </PO>   
</PurchaseOrders>
<PurchaseOrders>
    <!-- Group by Plant-Loc/Supplier -->
    <PO>
        <HOSTLOCID>100-0003</HOSTLOCID>
        <HOSTPARTID>500</HOSTPARTID>
        <HOSTVENDORLOCID>IC300</HOSTVENDORLOCID>
    </PO>
    <PO>
        <HOSTLOCID>100-0003</HOSTLOCID>
        <HOSTPARTID>800</HOSTPARTID>
        <HOSTVENDORLOCID>IC300</HOSTVENDORLOCID>
    </PO>   
</PurchaseOrders>
<PurchaseOrders >
    <!-- Group by Plant-Loc/Supplier -->
    <PO>
        <HOSTLOCID>100-0001</HOSTLOCID>
        <HOSTPARTID>200</HOSTPARTID>
        <HOSTVENDORLOCID>IC200</HOSTVENDORLOCID>
    </PO>
</PurchaseOrders>
<PO_Group>
```

The issue i am facing is even though i am able to group the elemnts, all the elements are other elements are being overwritten because of which i am loosing the data. Any suggestions on this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear why you create result elements in the XSLT that you haven't shown in the wanted output; perhaps simply grouping and wrapping and copying each group is all you need e.g.

```
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <PO_Group>
      <xsl:for-each-group select="PurchaseOrders/PO" composite="yes" group-by="HOSTLOCID, HOSTVENDORLOCID">
        <PurchaseOrders>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
        </PurchaseOrders>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
    </PO_Group>
  </xsl:template>
```

That is XSLT 3 with the `composite="yes"` (supported since Saxon 9.8 and Altova XML 2017 R3 I think), if you are stuck with an XSLT 2 processor use e.g.

```
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <PO_Group>
      <xsl:for-each-group select="PurchaseOrders/PO" group-by="concat(HOSTLOCID, '|', HOSTVENDORLOCID)">
        <PurchaseOrders>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
        </PurchaseOrders>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
    </PO_Group>
  </xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks Martin Honnen. The second example that you have suggested worked for me